# Find 5 greatest values for an attribute of a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The MongoDB site isn't working.

I am building an application with Meteor and I would like to select the 5 greatest values for an attribute in a collection. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
var items = MyCollection.find({}, {
  fields : { myAttribute :  1 }, // only fetch this filed
  sort   : { myAttribute : -1 }, // sort by myAttribute (from large to small)
  limit  : 5 // only take the first 5 elements
}).fetch();
```

This way you will receive documents with their `_id's` and `myAttribute`. If you only want the values, here's what you do:

```
var values = _.pluck(items, 'myAttribute');
```